# Android app crashes when trying to move to next screen after playing sound

Tags: android, media-player

I am making a basic class which plays a sound using one button and moves on to the next screen with a different button. The problem is that, after using the sound button, the next button crashes the app. I thought it was because I was releasing the sound and then checking for it, but it still crashes.

```
public class Explain1 extends Activity
{
    MediaPlayer mysound;
    protected boolean active = true;
    protected int splashtime = 17000;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.exp1);
        mysound=MediaPlayer.create(Explain1.this, R.raw.ex1 );
    }
    @Override
        protected void onDestroy()
        {

            super.onDestroy();
            mysound.stop();
            mysound.reset();
            mysound.release();
            mysound = null;
        }
    public void cont(View view) 
    {
        if(mysound.isPlaying())
        {
            mysound.stop();
            mysound.reset();
            mysound.release();

            Log.d("Exercise", "Sound Stopped");
        }
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.example","com.example.timestableseasy.Explain2");
        startActivity(i); 
    }

  public void listen(View view) 
    {
        mysound=MediaPlayer.create(Explain1.this, R.raw.ex1 );
        mysound.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mysound) 
            {
                mysound.stop();
                mysound.release();
                mysound=MediaPlayer.create(Explain1.this, R.raw.ex1 );
                Log.d("Exercise", "Sound PLayed");
            }

        });   
        mysound.start();

    }

}
```

here is the log cat.

```
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3814)
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17903)
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3809)
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611):    ... 11 more
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)  
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611):    at com.example.timestableseasy.Explain1.cont(Explain1.java:38)
06-10 14:35:39.444: E/AndroidRuntime(30611):    ... 14 more
```

It may be something simple, but I just can't see where the problem is.

Comment: it seems that the mediaPlayer is not valid at this time, when You trying to get the boolean MediaPlayer.isPlaying. instead of isPlaying check it with !=null...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not `release` the connection of `MediaPlayer`. Sufficient thing is to `reset`.

> **release()** :
>   This method releases any resource attached with MediaPlayer object
>
> **reset()**:
>   This method resets the media player

You need to do is

```
mp.reset();
mp.setDataSource(/*Code to provide data source*/);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Please check this [Media Player Example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/).

Comment: thanx that sorted it. i was releasing the sound so there wasn't any left over sounds